# Get the value of a field, given the hierarchical path

Tags: java, recursion

I have an object that contains sub properties, which also have sub properties and so on.

I basically need to find the best way to retrieve the value of a particular field on the object, given it's full hierarchical path as a string.

For example, if the object has the field company (Object) which has the field client (Object) which has the field id (String), this path will be represented as `company.client.id`. Therefore, given a path to the field i'm trying to get the value of on an object, how would I go about doing this?

Cheers.

Comment: You might need to use [`Field`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) class in `Reflection API`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please find below `Fieldhelper` class with `getFieldValue` method. 
It should allow you to solve your problem pretty quickly by 
splitting your string and then applying the the `getFieldValue` recursively, taking the result object as input for the next step.

```
package com.bitplan.resthelper;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

/**
 * Reflection help
 * @author wf
 *
 */
public class FieldHelper {

    /**
     * get a Field including superclasses
     * 
     * @param c
     * @param fieldName
     * @return
     */
    public Field getField(Class<?> c, String fieldName) {
        Field result = null;
        try {
            result = c.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException nsfe) {
            Class<?> sc = c.getSuperclass();
            result = getField(sc, fieldName);
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * set a field Value by name
     * 
     * @param fieldName
     * @param Value
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void setFieldValue(Object target,String fieldName, Object value) throws Exception {
        Class<? extends Object> c = target.getClass();
        Field field = getField(c, fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        // beware of ...
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldTrouble.html
        field.set(this, value);
    }

    /**
     * get a field Value by name
     * 
     * @param fieldName
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public Object getFieldValue(Object target,String fieldName) throws Exception {
        Class<? extends Object> c = target.getClass();
        Field field = getField(c, fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object result = field.get(target);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like yet another attempt to post URLs to your bitplan website. Also, your attempt to include a license is contrary to the license you agree to when you post content here in the first place. I am editing out your license text/link. **Do not add them back in**, or I will flag as spam.

Comment: Andrew it was not clear to me that the FAQ interpretation of the license is to allow to remove direct references to the author. This will be an obstacle for me to share more source code here. It is good to know this!

Comment: "The author" is you; you are already shown as the author by the author box that is on every post. If you were including someone *else's* code, you would have instead *had to* have included that information. However, if that other person's code was under a different license than the one you implicitly agree to when posting on SO, you usually can't post it at all.

Answer (score 29):

You can use [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtilsBean.html) `PropertyUtilsBean`.

Example of use :

```
PropertyUtilsBean pub = new PropertyUtilsBean();
Object property = pub.getProperty(yourObject, "company.client.id");
```

Comment: Accepted answer is good to learn but this answer is good to code.

Comment: This is rigth only when getter  and setter are defines

Comment: @Belin  can also add that the setter should return nothing (void), meaning this will not work for objects that implement fluent design/style (returning a reference to themselves). More [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEANUTILS-541).

Answer (score 2):

You need to first split your string to get individual `fieldNames`. Then for each field name, get the required information. You would have to iterate over your array of fieldNames.

You can try the below code. I have not used `Recursion` though, but it would work: -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String str = "company.client.id";
    String[] fieldNames = str.split("\\.");

    Field field;

    // Demo I have taken as first class that contains `company`
    Class<?> targetClass = Demo.class;  
    Object obj = new Demo();

    for (String fieldName: fieldNames) {

        field =  getFieldByName(targetClass, fieldName);    
        targetClass = field.getType();

        obj = getFieldValue(obj, field);            
        System.out.println(field + " : " + obj);

    }

}

public static Object getFieldValue(Object obj, Field field) throws Exception {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    return field.get(obj);
}

public static Field getFieldByName(Class<?> targetClass, String fieldName) 
                                                        throws Exception {
    return targetClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
}
```